# Java : Print hashmap of lists in O(n)

Tags: java, hashmap

Is it possible to print hashmap of lists in O(n) ?

I was about to do somethin like this :

```
for(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Edge>> e : map.entrySet()){
   for(Edge e1 : e.getValue())
      System.out.println(e.getKey() + " = "+ e1.Out());
}
```

but this is O(n^2)

my hashmap :

```
private Map<K, List<Edge<K,E>>> G = null;
```

I tried to do something like this :

```
public void getEdges(){
    getEdges(0);
}
private void getEdges(int i){
        if(i==this.G.size()){
            return;
        }else{
        List<Edge<K, E>> edgeList = this.G.get(this.G.keySet().toArray()[i]);
        for(Edge<K, E>  e : edgeList) {
            System.out.println("Edges : "+e.toString());
        }
        getEdges(i+1);
    }
}
```

But this is not O(n)

Comment: Why do you think the first example is not linear? What do you think `n` is here?

Comment: for what i know for inside for isnt n*n ? @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: Have you considered what "n" means?

Comment: "for inside for" is not sufficient to consider something `O(n^2)`. In your case if `n` is the total number of elements in all lists, you're still calling `System.out.println` n times, not n^2 times.

Comment: thanks @FedericoklezCulloca , i got it wrong.

Comment: And completely unrelated --  why are you doing this recursively rather than a for loop from `0 to G.size()`?  And the name `getEdges()` is questionable for a method that has a return type of `void`.  Perhaps `printEdges()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but this is O(n^2)

It is actually `O(E)` where `E` is the total number of edges.

And you cannot improve on that<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - At least, from the complexity perspective.</sup>